# Is there a way to Fourier transform $\cos\left(\sin (x)\right)$?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

In my physics problem, I encountered a solution has the form like $\cos\left(\sin (t)\right)$,
and I need to do the Fourier transform to this solution. Is there a way to do the Fourier transform analytically to $\cos\left(\sin (t)\right)$ on a certain range, say from $t=0$ to $t=2\pi$?
Or is there some way to manipulate $\cos\left(\sin (x)\right)$ and get an approximate expression which can be transformed analytically? The problem may be rephrased as to do the integral analytically or approximately:

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\cos{(\sin{(t)}})~e^{i\omega t}dt
$$

Thanks.

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion.